# How do I create disk partions using ubuntu that has already been launched?

Tags: disk, fdisk, disk-management, disk-image

Ive been trying to partion my disk using ubuntu but anytime I try to resize it it says error in unmounting...target is busy!How do I go about it since am a new user in ubuntu?

Comment: Are you trying to partition the disk which Ubuntu is running on?

Comment: If so, boot into a live usb and partition from there.

Comment: yes am trying to partiton the disk which ubuntu is running on. Will I not loose my data if I partiton from a live usb?

Comment: It is always recommended that you update/refresh your backup before any major change. Depending on what you do, you can lose data.

Comment: please how do I update/refresh my backup using ubuntu?